# get value from multidimensional array and store into associative array

Tags: php

I want to store all employee's salary as an $salary Array by looping the following multiimentional array.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

```
<?php   
$employees["employee 1"]["name"] = "Dana";
$employees["employee 1"]["title"] = "Owner";
$employees["employee 1"]["salary"] = "$60,000";

$employees["employee 2"]["name"] = "Matt";
$employees["employee 2"]["title"] = "Manager";
$employees["employee 2"]["salary"] = "$40,000";

$employees["employee 3"]["name"] = "Susan";
$employees["employee 3"]["title"] = "Cashier";
$employees["employee 3"]["salary"] = "$30,000";
?>
```

Comment: Based on your question, you know how to loop, and you know how to access elements of arrays.  What problem are you having?  In particular, you're looking for a foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code may help you:

```
$salary = array();
foreach ($employees as $key => $value) {
  $salary[$key] = $value['salary'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this like below code.

```
foreach($employees as $key =>$values){
    $emp[$key]['name'] = $values['name'];
    $emp[$key]['sal'] = $values['salary'];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($emp);
```

Out put will be :

```
Array
(
    [employee 1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Dana
            [sal] => $60,000
        )

    [employee 2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Matt
            [sal] => $40,000
        )

    [employee 3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Susan
            [sal] => $30,000
        )

)
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($employees as $employee) {
  foreach ($employee as $var => $val) {
    $$var[$employee] = $val;
  }
}
```

And then you should have three arrays, `$name`, `$title`, `$salary`.

Comment: Not what he asked for.  (Edit: Also, I tend to avoid variable variables when possible.  They're more ambiguous than a normal variable, and they rarely serve a purpose that an array would not be more suited to.)